# Swapping buttons on a GameCube controller

Tags: pcb, button, reverse-engineering

I have an old GameCube controller that I want to swap the buttons in.  By this I mean that I want to press the x button and have the signal for the r button sent.  I opened up the controller and found the locations of the buttons on the circuit board:

[image]

What I am wondering is how I repurpose the buttons.  Would it be as easy as scratching off the wire that runs to the r button and soldering it to a wire that comes from the x button?

Comment: You would most likely fail reassigning the buttons. The lines are covered by some protective material so you can't just rewire them. I'd more suggest getting a male and female adapter for the controller connector and remap the commands. Also, you wouldn't need to destroy the controller (which I'm generally against).

Comment: @bradman175 what are you talking about...

Comment: @Bradman175 hmmm that seems like good insight. I have some  concerns though.  I don't know how I would go about finding a male and female adapter for the GameCube controller (the port is custom designed by Nintendo and looks like this: http://www.raphnet.net/electronique/gc_to_nes/gamecube_connector_socket_labels.jpg) I would probably have to make the adapter or do some serious hacking.  Also what do you mean "remap" the commands. Do you mean use software to write some rules, or literally remap the commands with wiring in the adapter?

Comment: @Passerby Connect it to an arduino. Scratching until the lines get exposed could go very wrong.

Comment: No... it really won't.

Comment: @Bradman175 what do you mean "connect it to an arduino"? That's a pretty broad answer, how would one go about doing that?

Comment: @TylerHilbert Well that involves acquiring a female and male adapter for the GameCube controller, understanding what pins do what and their voltage levels, understanding their interface, wiring the controller through the arduino to the GameCube, programming the arduino to read and understand the pattern of signals (unless someone online has already done it), programming the arduino to replace the x button command with the r button and trying it out. Knowing the code for how to interface the GameCube through an arduino is out of my capabilities, for now.

Comment: @Passerby Well I just am simply not so fond of damaging controllers in that sense. But it's the OP decision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's the general method. You scratch off the solder mask, then cut the trace in half. Then you solder on a thin wire from one side of one trace to the other side of the other trace. Like an X/criss cross. That's it.

This is commonly done on arcade cabinet projects. [Here is a YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iWXL3oRQ2Yo) of a Xbox 360 controller rewired for southpaw usage.

The 360 controller is much more complex. The GameCube controller can be rewired with even a beginners soldering skills.

[image: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/iWXL3oRQ2Yo/maxresdefault.jpg]

Comment: Yes! This sounds like what I want to do.  I'm still a newb with electronics and don't know how I would go about actually doing this. Do you have any resources (videos, books, websites, etc) that could help get me started with this?

Comment: It's simple soldering. I added a video of this being done on a more complex controller. A Google search for GameCube arcade controller hack or mod would help you too.

Comment: I think I get the idea of how to do it.  I am not sure which part to scratch off though. How do I know which side of the buttons to scratch off?     Like,  There is a wire going into the button, and one going out. I am assuming that it is important that I cut the correct one.

Comment: @TylerHilbert the buttons are active low. The side that connects to the large green sections are the ground side. The side that connects to the thin trace go to the microcontroller. That's the side you need to cut and connect to.